# Obtener el numero de filas de una consulta SQL

Tags: base-de-datos, sql, subconsultas

tengo un problema en una consulta, en esta consulta tengo a los alumnos matriculados en una sección de un año especifico y sus promedios.
Mi objetivo es como puedo obtener el numero de alumnos que jalaron al menos un curso en dicho año.

```
select N.Descripcion as Nivel,G.Grado, S.Nombre as Seccion,A.Nombre,
M.MatriculaID
 ,AA.Denominacion as Periodo  , Promedio=AVG(E.Nota), c.Nombre as Curso  
from alumno A 
inner join Matricula M
ON A.AlumnoID=M.FK_AlumnoID
inner join AÑO_ACADEMICO aa
ON aa.AñoID=M.FK_AñoID
inner join SECCION S
ON S.SeccionID=M.FK_SeccionID
inner join Nivel N
ON N.NivelID=S.FK_NivelID
inner join Grado g
ON G.GradoID=S.FK_GradoID
inner join Evaluacion E
ON M.MatriculaID= E.FK_MatriculaID 
inner join Bimestre B
ON B.BimestreID=E.FK_BimestreID AND B.FK_AñoID=AA.AñoID
inner join detalle_curso DC
ON DC.DetalleCursoID=E.FK_DetalleCursoID
inner join curso c
ON C.CursoID=DC.FK_CursoID
 Group by N.Descripcion,G.Grado,S.Nombre,A.Nombre,M.MatriculaID,AA.Denominacion ,C.Nombre 
 having AVG(E.Nota)<10.5
 order by AA.Denominacion,N.Descripcion,G.Grado,S.Nombre,A.Nombre asc
```

Otro problema es que si el alumno jalo dos cursos en un año, quiero contarlo como uno.
Actualmente el resultado de mi consulta es esta.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para que te cuente los alumnos como uno puede usar [SQL SELECT DISTINCT Statement](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_distinct.asp).
El código te quedaría así:

```
select DISTINCT M.MatriculaID, N.Descripcion as Nivel,G.Grado, S.Nombre as 
Seccion,A.Nombre, AA.Denominacion as Periodo  , Promedio=AVG(E.Nota), c.Nombre as 
Curso  
from alumno A 
inner join Matricula M
ON A.AlumnoID=M.FK_AlumnoID
inner join AÑO_ACADEMICO aa
ON aa.AñoID=M.FK_AñoID
inner join SECCION S
ON S.SeccionID=M.FK_SeccionID
inner join Nivel N
ON N.NivelID=S.FK_NivelID
inner join Grado g
ON G.GradoID=S.FK_GradoID
inner join Evaluacion E
ON M.MatriculaID= E.FK_MatriculaID 
inner join Bimestre B
ON B.BimestreID=E.FK_BimestreID AND B.FK_AñoID=AA.AñoID
inner join detalle_curso DC
ON DC.DetalleCursoID=E.FK_DetalleCursoID
inner join curso c
ON C.CursoID=DC.FK_CursoID
 Group by N.Descripcion,G.Grado,S.Nombre,A.Nombre,M.MatriculaID,AA.Denominacion ,C.Nombre 
 having AVG(E.Nota)<10.5
 order by AA.Denominacion,N.Descripcion,G.Grado,S.Nombre,A.Nombre asc
```

Para contar la cantidad de alumnos que tomaron al menos un curso. Podrias usar [SQL COUNT()](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_count_avg_sum.asp). El código de quedaría así:

```
select COUNT(DISTINCT M.MatriculaID) 
from alumno A 
inner join Matricula M
ON A.AlumnoID=M.FK_AlumnoID
inner join AÑO_ACADEMICO aa
ON aa.AñoID=M.FK_AñoID
inner join SECCION S
ON S.SeccionID=M.FK_SeccionID
inner join Nivel N
ON N.NivelID=S.FK_NivelID
inner join Grado g
ON G.GradoID=S.FK_GradoID
inner join Evaluacion E
ON M.MatriculaID= E.FK_MatriculaID 
inner join Bimestre B
ON B.BimestreID=E.FK_BimestreID AND B.FK_AñoID=AA.AñoID
inner join detalle_curso DC
ON DC.DetalleCursoID=E.FK_DetalleCursoID
inner join curso c
ON C.CursoID=DC.FK_CursoID
 Group by N.Descripcion,G.Grado,S.Nombre,A.Nombre,M.MatriculaID,AA.Denominacion ,C.Nombre 
 having AVG(E.Nota)<10.5
 order by AA.Denominacion,N.Descripcion,G.Grado,S.Nombre,A.Nombre asc
```

Espero que te sirva. Saludos!

Comment: Agradesco tu respuesta amigo! pero no me funciona , no me funciona :(

Comment: Que resultado obtienes? te muestra algún error o el resultado no es el esperado?

Comment: Ejecuto el distinct, pero me aparece algunas filas con el mismo codigo..., necesito obtener el numero porque  quiero obtenerlo para una medida y asi poblar una tabla hecho.

Comment: Se me ocurrio quitarle los valores que hacia que el select se vean valores distintos en este caso era el Promedio y el Nombre de Curso, los quite y le puse el distinct y me funciono gracias.

Comment: De nada. Saludos!